# How to retrieve checked property from dynamically generated Checkboxes?

Tags: java, android-layout, android-widget

I'm facing a problem determining whether the checkboxes are checked. This is because they are dynamically generated. I attempted to create the OnCheckedChangeListener() for each of the dynamic checkboxes, but it was identified that only the last dynamic checkbox's OnCheckedChangeListener() gets executed.

Here's my code snippet (Hope it will be helpful):

```
public class yc_SubmitAttendance_ClassMode extends Activity {

Context myContext = this;
myDbAdapter myDB = null;
Cursor myCur = null;
Spinner mySpin = null;

TableLayout tl = null;

CheckBox myCB = null;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yc_studattend_classmode_layout);

    mySpin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinClassModeSelectModGrp);

    myDB = new myDbAdapter(myContext);

    tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.classModeTableLayout);
            //retrieve dynamic data
            myCur = myDB.retrieveAttnForSelectedMod(mySpin.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString());

            myCur.moveToFirst();

            for(byte rowNo=0;rowNo<myCur.getCount();rowNo++)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(myContext);

                /*Some codes intentionally left missing */

                myCB = new CheckBox(myContext);
                myCB.setId(rowNo);

                //Setting a onCheckedListener on each of the checkbox generated

                myCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0,
                            boolean arg1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        myCur.moveToPosition(myCB.getId());

                        if(myCB.isChecked())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(myContext,"Attendance deducted to " + ((myCur.getFloat(2)) - 2) + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(myContext,"Attendance reverting to " + (myCur.getFloat(2)) + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }

                });

                //Insert the checkbox onto this row
                tr.addView(myCB);

                //Append this row to the TableLayout
                tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                myCur.moveToNext();

            } //end of for-loop
      } // end of onCreate
}//end of class
```

But, what I want is to be able to determine each dynamic checkbox whether they are checked or not checked.

Yeong Chai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute this code in:

```
            myCB.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton thisCheckBox,
                        boolean isChecked) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    myCur.moveToPosition(thisCheckBox.getId());

                    if(isChecked)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(myContext,"Attendance deducted to " + ((myCur.getFloat(2)) - 2) + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(myContext,"Attendance reverting to " + (myCur.getFloat(2)) + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
```

The problem was you were using myCB.isChecked() instead the second parameter "arg1" to determine whether the CheckBox was checked or not.  myCB will always point at the last CheckBox you create because you assign it each time you loop through.

Comment: Hii Grazahd, thanks for your quick response. It works like a champ now and it clarified my understanding for the **onCheckedChangeListener()**. A worthy thumbsup.